# How to adjust the logo in the nav bar without croping the actual logo , where i am creating a wed D project using react js

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skQbb.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skQbb.png)[

```js
import consultin2 from '../../assets/logo/consultin2.png';

inside function
{
<nav>
        <div className="navbar-logo">
        <img src={consultin2} alt="ConsultIn"></img>
        
        </div>
        
        .......</nav>

}
```

```css
 .navbar-logo{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0%;
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    /* max-width: 250px; */
    
}
```

][1][enter image description here][2]I am totally stuck and frustrated in the logo part of my Web Development project. I am unable to adjust the logo in the navbar , if I am trying to do so
then I am getting these types problems:

1. If logo , fit the navbar then width of the nav bar increases , but I don't want to increase the width of the navbar.

2.If however I  am able to adjust the logo in the nav bar then my logo gets cropped  , which I don't want to do .

I only want to adjust my logo in the left side in my navigation bar width top = 0%, bottom=0% and left=0%  without cropping my logo and without increasing the width of my navigation bar.

I have used .png format image.

[enter image description here][3]

Comment: please fix your code and make sure it's running properly in the snippet so we can help.

Comment: Are you saying that the navbar width changes even thouth the logo has position absolute? Also,is there a reason for ithe logo being in an element rather than just a background image on the navbar? And what styling has nav got?

Answer (score 0):

### This might help

#### Solution 1 -> Using Calc():

1. Set either the width or the height of the logo. **[Because if you set both then the logo's ratio will change]**
2. Use the `calc()` function of css to subtract the extra width or height.

#### Solution 2 -> Using Position:

1. If you want to use positioning, then first use `position:relative` to navbar.
2. Then set `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;` to logo;

#### Solution 3 -> Flexbox:

1. Set `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;` to navbar. **In this case, you might have to wrap other elements than logo in a `<div>`
2. Make sure to control `margin` and `padding` of navbar and logo to get the desired design.